# Remove instance of object IF it exists on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I'm trying to check if there is an instance of an object on screen, and IF there is - remove it. The code is as follows -

```
if (gracetarget.parent)
{
 gracetarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gracetarget.graceListener);
 gracetarget.parent.removeChild(gracetarget);
}
else if (springtarget.parent)
{
 springtarget.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, springtarget.springListener);
 springtarget.parent.removeChild(springtarget);
}
```

I get the following error -
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

I guess it's because I'm trying to remove an object that doesn't exist, but surely the IF statement should only run if the object exists?

Answer (score 2):

First test if the object you want to remove is not null.

```
if (gracetarget != null && gracetarget.parent) {
...
}
```

If gracetarget is typed (MovieClip for example) you can do

```
if (gracetarget is MovieClip && gracetarget.parent) {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: That gets rid of the error message, but it doesn't remove the listener or the movieclip from the stage. What I'm trying to do is change the players sprite from on e thing to another. So while the code is adding a new movieclip, its not removing the old one, or its listener.

Comment: @DanLibert Where are you calling the removal object from? If it's a component constructor, it might just be that it's not on the stage yet.

Comment: The listener and the object should be removed with the IF statements that I posted above. I've just added a trace to the IF statements, and they're not firing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason gracetarget/springtarget is not getting removed from stage is because somewhere else in your code your setting it to null. You are losing these variables somewhere in your code.

Go through the code of your class once again and check which places you are setting gracetarget/springtarget and trace it. Also check if you are setting its value from outside the class, and put distinct traces at all such places for debuggung

If the variables gracetarget or springtarget is being set to null, the actual movieclips remain on stage since gracetarget and springtarget are just pointers to the actual movieclip.

I am sure you can debug this one easily. Best of luck.